# Access Windows 10 IoT partition on SD card

Tags: sd-card, windows-iot, partition

I got a 16Gb micro SD to use in a raspberry pi 3, and today I installed the OS with the program downloaded from microsoft website. However I noticed that the SD card was formatted in a strange way: a main 64Mb FAT partition, a 600Mb,a 4.2Gb and another 2,5Gb all unkown and not recognized by windows. Also 8Gb of unallocated space. I know this is normal, but how can I access the data partition? What if I want to deploy a large file inside my card?

Comment: What did you use to format it?

Comment: I have used the Windos IoT core installer that flashed the SD card and partitioned it

Comment: No, I'm asking what you used to clear the SD card before hand.

Comment: I bought it today at supermarket and it was formatted with FAT32, I just inserted into my pc and flashed it, nothing else

Comment: If you have a Windows PC, download the official SD Card Formatter and format it completely there. The Windows 10 IoT installer should set up partitions for you.

Comment: I don't think it's a partitioning problem: I've already done some research and it appears that it always does like this, I was just trying to figure out a method to put files on the data partition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like there is no way to do it from the SD card, but because I installed Windows IoT, there is a built-in FTP and file sharing server. To access them, just turn the raspberry on and:

- for the FTP connect to ftp://
- for file sharing open file explorer and type \\c$